# append string to varchar2 field based on the value of another field

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Table 1 has

```
col1 varchar2(85) 
col2 date
```

There is plenty of character space available in col1.  If col2 value is previous to 2001, need to append to whatever value is in col1 the value `OLD` to the front end of whatever value may be in col1.

In some cases, col1 will be NULL.  At most it will have values less than 40 characters in length.

Is there a SQL statement that can accomplish this without getting into PL/SQL?

Appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will also work in only one SQL statement as it will update all rows having value less than 2001...

```
update TAB1 set col1='OLD ' || nvl(COL1, '') where to_char(COL2, 'yyyy') < 2001;
```

Comment: Without further understanding of the db, I don't think that is good advice. You might break a running system. Also: if col1 is prepended with 'OLD' this might be longer than 85 chars for certaian values.

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following should work:

```
select case when to_char(COL2, 'yyyy') < 2001
            then 'OLD ' || nvl(COL1, '')
            else COL1 end case
from   TAB1
```

For example:

```
insert into TAB1 values ('testpost2001', trunc(sysdate));

insert into TAB1 values ('testpre2001', '01/Jul/2000');

insert into TAB1 values (null, trunc(sysdate));

insert into TAB1 values (null, '01/Jul/2000');

select COL1, COL2,
       case when to_char(COL2, 'yyyy') < 2001
       then 'OLD ' || nvl(COL1, '')
       else COL1 end case
from   TAB1;
```

Returns:

```
COL1           COL2          CASE
testpost2001   15/12/2011    testpost2001
testpre2001    1/07/2000     OLD testpre2001
               15/12/2011    
                1/07/2000    OLD
```

Comment: You might consider using `case when to_char(col2, 'yyyy') < '2001' then 'OLD' end || col1 end` so as to have an explicit reference to `col` only once.

Comment: Not sure you need to to_char COL2, it would be more efficient to compare the date with a date e.g. `col2 < to_date('01/01/2011','dd/mm/yyyy')